# Ubuntu on dl380p gen8 won't boot from SD Card after few restarts and powering off

Tags: ubuntu, hp-proliant, boot, sd-card

I have two HP Proliant dl380p gen8 servers with full array (25 disks). I did install SD Card into the internal slot on motherboard. Changed USB setup in bios to Internal SD card first.
After successful installation of Ubuntu Server 20.04 (through mounting virtual media in Remote console) and setup I did restart few times and everything was OK.

I turned off the power (plug out from the wall), changed few disks, erased disks from Intelligent Provisioning, rebuilded the array, restarted and OS will simply not boot no matter what I change in BIOS or what boot device I select.

Everytime I get PXE-E61: Media test failure check cable and PXE-M0F - Exiting QLogic PXE ROM.
This happened on BOTH my servers with SD cards today (both SD cards with Ubuntu Server 20.04. iLo shows "SD-Card Status
Present: 64 GB" on both of them, so SD cards are okay.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Can I somehow boot from SD card with help of Ubuntu Live CD or other tools/usb bootloader?

Thanks a lot for every answer.